# How to change background color of DataColumn in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a `DataTable` widget for displaying some data in tabular format. I wasn't able to find any way to change the background color of the `DataColumn`, it defaults to white.

I tried wrapping the `label` inside a `Container` but that does not help since the container takes the dimensions of the child.

Is there any easier way to set the background color of `DataColum'?

Below is some code for reference -

```
DataTable(
  dataRowHeight: 70,
  headingRowHeight: 60,
  rows: List.generate(4, (index) {
    return DataRow(
      cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(
          Text("Number",),
        ),
        DataCell(
          Text(
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
          ),
        ),
      ]
    );
  }),
  columns: [
    DataColumn(
      label: Text("Name"),
    ),
    DataColumn(
      label: Text("Description"),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Did you find the answer to the question? I need answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Now in flutter version 1.22, you can do it like this

```
DataTable(
    headingRowColor:
        MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.blue),
    columns: [
       DataColumn(),
       DataColumn(),
                
    ],
           
    rows: [
      DataRow(
          cells: [
              DataCell(),
              DataCell(),
          ],
      ),
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still looking for an answer to this, I found out that it can be done by using `IntrinsicWidth`, `Stack` and `Container`. I have modified the height based on thebuggycoder's question which is `60`. As The default `dataRowHeight` of `DataTable` widget is kMinInteractiveDimension, you can replace that accordingly!

```
     IntrinsicWidth(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 60, // default would be kMinInteractiveDimension
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              DataTable(
                dataRowHeight: 70,
                headingRowHeight: 60,
                rows: List.generate(4, (index) {
                  return DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[
                    DataCell(
                      Text(
                        "Number",
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Text(
                        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]);
                }),
                columns: [
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text("Name"),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text("Description"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 DataTable(
          showCheckboxColumn: false,
          dataRowHeight: 35,
          headingRowHeight: 35,
          columns: <DataColumn>[//column list],
          rows: List.generate( // use this instead of map()
            yourlist.length, (index) {
            return DataRow(
              color: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) {
                return index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.black; //make tha magic!
              }),
              cells: [//cells list],
            );
          },
         ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]Newer version of flutter unable to set color in `DataRow()` but you can set color in `DataTable` like the example below.

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]DataTable(
    headingRowColor:
    MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.blue),
    dataRowColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.grey),
    columns: const <DataColumn>[
      DataColumn(
        label: Text(
          'Profesional',
          style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Text(
          'Entregados',
          style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Text(
          'Aceptado',
          style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Text(
          'Rechazado',
          style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Text(
          'Pendiente',
          style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Text(
          'Total',
          style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Text(
          'Precio Aceptado',
          style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Text(
          'Precio Rechazado',
          style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Text(
          'Precio Pendiente',
          style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
    ],
    rows: const <DataRow>[
      DataRow(
        cells: <DataCell>[
          DataCell(Text('Iván Molina Pastor',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),)),
          DataCell(Text('1',style:TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent),)),
          DataCell(Text('1',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightGreen),),),
          DataCell(Text('0',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),)),
          DataCell(Text('0',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orangeAccent),)),
          DataCell(Text('€ 36.30',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo),)),
          DataCell(Text('€ 36.30',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightGreen),)),
          DataCell(Text('€ 0.00',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),)),
          DataCell(Text('€ 0.00',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellowAccent),)),
        ],
      ),
      DataRow(
        cells: <DataCell>[
          DataCell(Text('Juan Celdran Alenda',style:TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),)),
          DataCell(Text('3',style:TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent),)),
          DataCell(Text('2',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightGreen),),),
          DataCell(Text('0',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),)),
          DataCell(Text('0',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orangeAccent),)),
          DataCell(Text('€ 8,433.70',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo),)),
          DataCell(Text('€ 6,316.20',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightGreen),)),
          DataCell(Text('€ 0.00',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),)),
          DataCell(Text('€ 2,117.50',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellowAccent),)),
        ],
      ),

    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add decoration to `datatable`
and to override it, you can use its `dataRowColor` property as if in my code

```
Widget landData() => DataTable(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
        end: Alignment.centerRight,
        // 10% of the width, so there are ten blinds.
        colors: <Color>[
          ColorUtils.greenGradientColor1,
          ColorUtils.greenGradientColor2,
          ColorUtils.greenGradientColor1
        ],
        // red to yellow
        tileMode: TileMode
            .repeated, // repeats the gradient over the canvas
      ),
      border: Border.all(color:Colors.white,width:2),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)
  ),
  onSelectAll: (b) {},
  //sortColumnIndex: 1,
  sortAscending: true,
  columnSpacing: 12,
  horizontalMargin: 0,
  //headingRowColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) {return ColorUtils.greenlabelColor;},),
  dataRowColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) {return Colors.white;},),
  headingRowHeight: 30,
  columns: <DataColumn>[
    DataColumn(
      label: Text("Khasra No.", textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: CommonTextStyles.formLabelStyle,),
      numeric: false,
      // onSort: (i, b) {
      //   print("$i $b");
      //   setState(() {
      //     //names.sort((a, b) => a.firstName.compareTo(b.firstName));
      //   });
      // },
      tooltip: "To display Khasra No",
    ),
    DataColumn(
      label: Text("Plot No.", textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
      numeric: false,
      // onSort: (i, b) {
      //   //print("$i $b");
      //   setState(() {
      //     //names.sort((a, b) => a.lastName.compareTo(b.lastName));
      //   });
      // },
      tooltip: "To display Plot No",
    ),
    DataColumn(
      label: Text("Area (In ha).", textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
      numeric: false,
      onSort: (i, b) {
        //print("$i $b");
        setState(() {
          //names.sort((a, b) => a.lastName.compareTo(b.lastName));
        });
      },
      tooltip: "To display Plot No",
    ),
  ],
  rows: lstLandInfo
      .map(
        (name) => DataRow(
      cells: [
        DataCell(
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Text(name.khasrano),
              Text('Latitude:'),
            ],
          ),
          showEditIcon: false,
          placeholder: false,
        ),
        DataCell(
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Text(name.plotno),
              Text('0.23587'),
            ],
          ),
          showEditIcon: false,
          placeholder: false,
        ),
        DataCell(
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Text(name.area),
              Text('Longitude:' + " 0.25845"),
            ],
          ),
          showEditIcon: false,
          placeholder: false,
        )
      ],
    ),
  )
      .toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

On a easy way if you want to highlight your column, instead of changing the background, change the color of text in DataColumn.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable(
            showBottomBorder: true,
            dataRowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
            headingRowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black),
            headingRowHeight: 30.0,
            dataRowHeight: 20.0,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            sortColumnIndex: 0,
            sortAscending: true,
            headingTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
            dataTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 12),

            columns: const <DataColumn>[
              DataColumn(
                label: Text(
                  'Name',
                  style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                ),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text(
                  'Age',
                  style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                ),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text(
                  'Role',
                  style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                ),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text(
                  'Date',
                  style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                ),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text(
                  'Authority',
                  style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                ),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text(
                  'Date',
                  style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                ),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text(
                  'Description',
                  style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                ),
              ),
            ],
            rows: const <DataRow>[
              DataRow(
                cells: <DataCell>[
                  DataCell(Text('Ravi')),
                  DataCell(Text('19')),
                  DataCell(Text('Student')),
                  DataCell(Text('08-10-2020')),
                  DataCell(Text('Null')),
                  DataCell(Text('02-03-2020')),
                  DataCell(Text('A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. ')),
                ],
              ),
              DataRow(
                cells: <DataCell>[
                  DataCell(Text('Jane')),
                  DataCell(Text('43')),
                  DataCell(Text('Professor')),
                  DataCell(Text('08-10-2020')),
                  DataCell(Text('Null')),
                  DataCell(Text('02-03-2020')),
                  DataCell(Text('A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. ')),

                ],
              ),
              DataRow(
                cells: <DataCell>[
                  DataCell(Text('William')),
                  DataCell(Text('27')),
                  DataCell(Text('Professor')),
                  DataCell(Text('08-10-2020')),
                  DataCell(Text('Null')),
                  DataCell(Text('02-03-2020')),
                  DataCell(Text('A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. ')),

                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score -1):

`Container` with `BoxDecoration` -> `Column`/`Row` -> `DataTable`

You can use the `BoxDecoration`'s `gradient` property too.

Check this tutorial: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0S-95xTxsAg) 
Code Sample: [GitHub](https://github.com/whatsupcoders/Flutter-Tables/blob/master/lib/homepage.dart)

```
child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
          color: Color(0xff5a348b),
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Color(0xffebac38), Color(0xffde4d2a)],
              begin: Alignment.centerRight,
              end: Alignment(-1.0, -2.0)), //Gradient
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  DataTable(
                    columns: <DataColumn>[
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text(
                          'Storage',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text(
                          '1TB',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                    rows: <DataRow>[
                      DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            'Smart synchronization',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                          Icon(
                            Icons.add,
                            color: Colors.white54,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]),
                      DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            'Full text search',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                          Icon(
                            Icons.edit,
                            color: Colors.white54,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: I don't wish to change the background of the entire `DataTable`. I need to change the background only for the table headers i.e. the `DataColumn` widgets.

Comment: you aren't answering the question, he's only want to change DataColumn background-color